# The number of matrices that have their trace divisible by $3$ in the set $S$ of all matrices with exactly three $0$s, $1$s and $2$s.

Tags: matrices, permutations

> Let S be the set of all $3\times 3$ matrices such that the 9 entries comprise of exactly three $0$'s, three $1$'s, and three $2$'s. The number of matrices in $S$ that have their trace divisible by $3$ is?

I've been trying to solve this as follows:

The possible values of the trace that are divisible by $3$ are $0,3,6$.

$0$ and $6$ are attained just one way. $3$ is attained once by all the diagonal entries being $1$. Lastly $3$ can be attained by any combination of $0,1$ and $2.$

So, there are $\displaystyle\frac{3!\cdot6!}{2!\cdot2!\cdot2!}+3$ possible cases.

The $3!$ in the numerator is the number of ways to arrange $0,1$ and $2.$ The $6!$ divided by the $2!$ three times is the number of ways to arrange the other six entries accounting for the twofold repetition of the other three values.

My answer's incorrect. Could someone help me understand what's wrong with my thinking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 and 6 are not attained just one way - they are attained in $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$ ways, accounting for all the ways you can arrange the other (non-diagonal) elements. Similarly for the trace=3 case where you have all 1's on the diagonal.